# retrieving data and storing in three different objects and then to arraylist

Tags: java, servlets

Hello I want to retrieve data from database and that will be stored in three different objects and i want to store those objects into arraylist and again want to show that three objects data in to jsp as three types of data .I can do for one objects but how can I do for the three objects.Any idea?

this is my servlet code

```
public class ViewCasualStaff extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, java.io.IOException{

        try {
            PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("text/html");

            Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("");
            String sql = "SELECT LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE "
                    + "WHERE  JOB_TYPE = casual";

            pst.executeQuery(sql);
            ResultSet rs = pst.getResultSet();

            ArrayList<CasualStaff> casualStafflist = new ArrayList<>();

            while(rs.next()){

                CasualStaff cs = new CasualStaff();
                cs.setFname(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
                cs.setLname(rs.getString("LAST_NAME"));
                casualStafflist.add(cs);

            }

            request.setAttribute("CSList",casualStafflist);

            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp");

            dispatcher.forward(request,response);
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(ViewCasualStaff.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Below this the interface class and other classes that implements interface class

```
* @author dipendra
*/

public interface Staff {

    public String FName= "Fname";
    public String LName ="Lname";
    public String Postion = "Position";

    public void setStaff(String Fname,String Lname,String Position);
}
```

this class is implementing staff interface

```
public class  CasualStaff implements Staff{

    private String Fname;
    private String Lname;
    private String Position;

    @Override
    public void setStaff(String Fname, String Lname, String Position) {
        this.Fname= Fname;
        this.Lname=Lname;
        this.Position = Position;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the problem, why can't you follow the same process?

Comment: you mean I have to create new arraylist and add second objects and likewise for third one or ?

Comment: Yes, and set the three arraylist as `request` attributes.

Comment: I don't know nothing of your data, but maybe you can retrieve the desired data in the same sql consult? Then you can wrap them all in just one object, and do it just one time

Comment: the above sql sorts out the casual people and like wise i need to sort out full time people and part time from the table.how can i do that in sql and could you also give some example how to wrap them in objects

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you are calculating average from three different tables using group by statement which returns multiple rows.
 - Fist I have written three different queries from different tables
 - Second I have  Created three Arraylist objects (firstArr, secondArr, thirdArr)     to store resultset
 - Third I have created one more arralist object and "Add three objects" into this finalArr object.

At the end you will have a finalArr Object which contains all the resultsets data.

Now you can iterate through the finalArr and show the result into your jsp or desired views

```
public ArrayList getAverage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub`enter code here`
    String query1= "select sum(column)/count(Column) as avr1 from table1 group by(column1) order by desc";
    String query2= "Select sum(column)/count(Column) as avr2 from table2 group by(column1) order by desc";
    String query3= "select sum(column)/count(Column) as avr3 from table3 group by(column1) order by desc";      

    Connection connection = null;   
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ArrayList fisrtArr = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList secondArr = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList thirdArr = new ArrayList();
    float average1= 0;
    float average2= 0;
    float average3= 0;
    try {
         connection = dataSourceAbacus.getConnection();
         preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query1);
         rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
            average1= rs.getInt("avr1");
            firstArr.add(average1);
        }
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }if (rs != null){
            try{rs.close();
            }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }if(preparedStatement != null){
            try{preparedStatement.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    try {
         connection = dataSourceAbacus.getConnection();
         preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query2);
         rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
            average2= rs.getInt("avr2");
            secondArr.add(average2);
        }
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }if (rs != null){
            try{rs.close();
            }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }if(preparedStatement != null){
            try{preparedStatement.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    try {
         connection = dataSourceAbacus.getConnection();
         preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query3);
         rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
            average3 = rs.getFloat("avr3");
            thirdArr.add(average3);
        }
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }if (rs != null){
            try{rs.close();
            }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }if(preparedStatement != null){
            try{preparedStatement.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    finalArr.add(firstArr);
    finalArr.add(secondArr);
    finalArr.add(thirdArr);
    return finalArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your three objects. A smart way in your case would be:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, java.io.IOException{

    try {
        PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("");

        String[] jobTypes = {"casual", "full time", "part time"};
        ArrayList<Staff>[] myData = new ArrayList<>()[jobTypes.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < jobTypes.length; i++) {
            String sql = "SELECT LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE "
                    + "WHERE  JOB_TYPE = " + jobTypes[i];

            pst.executeQuery(sql);
            ResultSet rs = pst.getResultSet();

            ArrayList<Staff> staffList= new ArrayList<>();

            while(rs.next()) {

                Staff cs = new Staff();
                cs.setFname(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
                cs.setLname(rs.getString("LAST_NAME"));
                staffList.add(cs);

            }
            myData[i] = staffList;
        }

        request.setAttribute("SList", myData );      

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp");

        dispatcher.forward(request,response);
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ViewCasualStaff.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }     
}
```

You will have to create a java Interface `Staff` implemented by `CasualStaff`, `FullTimeStaff` and `PartTimeStaff` to do this code possible. First and last names need to be in the interface. It would be also smarter ;)

Hope to helped you

Comment: @Dipen I did the same process for the three objects in a compact way.

Comment: * @author dipendra
 */



public interface Staff {
    
    public String FName= "Fname";
    public String LName ="Lname";
    public String Postion = "Position";
    
    
   public void setStaff(String Fname,String Lname,String Position);
  
    
    
}

Comment: @Dipen yes that's the interface. You don't need to initialice the attributes that way `Fname = "Fname"`. Your constructor will do it.

Comment: okey i got that i dont need constructor now in the casual staff do i create a staff object and store and call the setStaff method and store all the values there and the display the whole staff object in my jsp page or what pls need a guidance?